Zero cmd_vel while using custom nav2 Behavior
I have created a custom behavior tree plugin which detects an AprilTag and tries to follow it. The behavior plugins publishes a command velocity after on the cmd_vel topic. The issue I'm facing is when the behavior is running, there seems to be some other publisher on the cmd_vel topic which is publishing a zero msg. Another weird thing is the zero messages are not exactly zero. The linear.y is populated with a very small value in the order of 10e-6.
Things I've checked:

Checked if any message is being published to cmd_vel_nav but there is no message
Checked the publish rate, the rate is 30Hz but the expected rate is 10Hz (Publish once per tick of the tree)
There are 9 publishers to the topic, one per behavior and the velocity smoother.

In the BT, Follow marker is the node that publishes the cmd_vel. The node graph can be viewed with this link
Node Graph

Cycle update code to publish the cmd_vel. The info shows that there is no zero published.
    Status FollowMarker::onCycleUpdate(){
        if(left_st && right_st){
            return Status::SUCCEEDED;
        }
        //Calculate the command velocity
        ret_msg = calculate_cmd_vel();

        if(failures > 2){
            return Status::FAILED;
        }

        this->vel_pub_->publish(ret_msg);
        RCLCPP_INFO(logger_, "Published Linear %.2f Angular %.2f", ret_msg.linear.x, ret_msg.angular.z);
        return Status::RUNNING;
    }


The problem was the velocity smoother was running in closed loop mode which was taking feedback from odometry. The last command was zero and hence the output cmd_vel was constantly zero at the 20Hz which is the rate of the velocity smoother (Hence adding to 10Hz to create 30Hz on cmd_vel).
